# How can I assign List Values to a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I have a string `result="Out of Service"` .And I want to update it to its short form if it matches with full name by comparing with a list that has values like attached image :

[image: here]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Linq

```
var result = "Out of Service";
result = shortForms.FirstOrDefault(model => model.Name == result)?.ShortName ?? result;
```

Comment: thanks for quick response

Comment: can you please explain this : " ?.ShortName" ,how does this work and what is the use of ? before ShortName (PS: I'm new to this)

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` will loop over `shortForms` items until it finds the item that satisfies the `==` condition, **if such an item not found**: it will return `null`, in this case, you can't call `.ShortName` on null because it will throw `NullReferenceException`, to avoid this, use [`?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) operator, it will not call `.ShortName`, this way, the result of `shortForms.FirstOrDefault(model => model.Name == result)?.ShortName` will be null,

Comment: in this case [`??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) will return the current value of `result` to keep it as it was and not assign null to it.

Comment: thank you so much Sulaiman ,it means a lot